# Regular Expression to retrieve column and tables from SQL statement

Tags: java, sql, regex

I need to get all columns and all tables from an SQL statement, let's say:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name FROM table1 as t1 LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t2.id=t1.id INNER JOIN table3 as t3 ON t3.id=t1.id WHERE t1.id=1
```

The output needs to be:

```
Columns[] = { {"u","id"}, {"u","name"} }
Tables[] = { {"t1","table1"}, {"t2","table2"}, {"t3","table3"} }
```

I tried the following but i just get the two first table names

```
^SELECT\s*.*\s*FROM\s*([a-z_]*).*\sJOIN\s*([a-z_]*).*$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL grammar is too complicated to extract this sort of information with a regular expression; you'll need a SQL parser.

You might consider ANTLR's predefined SQL grammar or [JSqlParser](http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: yeah! that's a nice tip. I will try.